# can not convert to json response to camel case newtonsoft.json and Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.24

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure-functions

I'm trying to convert the keys in a json response from Pascalcase to camelCase
I'm using  Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.24 ,newtonsoft.json 12.0.1 and visual studio 16.2

```
req.GetConfiguration().Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

but it is not working and I'm getting this error

> Method not found: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.get_SerializerSettings()'

I tried to downgrade newtonsoft.json 9.0.1
it's not working too, and here is the error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

I also found [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/using-newtonsoft-json-in-a-visual-studio-extension/) about the lowest Newtonsoft.Json version supported in each [visual studio  version](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/using-newtonsoft-json-in-a-visual-studio-extension/)

I spent two days trying to solve this ,
any suggestions about what should I do to fix this  !

Answer (score 2):

The way that I see it, you have a couple of options here.
You should be able to convert your Pascal cased json string using a method along these lines;

```
    [FunctionName("JsonDeserializeObject")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
          [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
          ILogger log) {

        var jsonBody = await req.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var description = DeserializeTypeCamelCase<Description>(jsonBody);
        var camelCaseJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(description);

        return new OkObjectResult(camelCaseJson);
    }

    public static T DeserializeTypeCamelCase<T>(string json) {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        };
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, settings);
    }

    public class Description {
        public string title;
        public string units;
        public string basePeriod;
    }
}
```

However, I do not understand the bounds you face with what you can do. I would recommend using Regex to edit your json string. It would also be faster. You may have to parse a lot of data at a time, and serializing and deserializing it is just not a great idea.

```
    public static string RegexCamelCaseJson(string json) {
        return Regex.Replace(json, "\"([A-Z])(\\w+?)\":",
            match => @$"""{match.Groups[1].Value.ToLower()}{match.Groups[2]}"":");
    }
```

This function, RegexCamelCaseJson, should do exactly what you're looking for and faster.

Comment: when i use  JsonConvert.SerializeObject  and then   return req.req.CreateResponse(...., response )     my result look like this "{\"key\" : \"value\", \"key\" : \"value\"}"  , but I want something like this   {"key" : "value", "key" : "value"}

Comment: So when you look at json from the local watch in the debugger, it will add escape chars for the quotes. If you view it with the "Text Visualizer" from the debugger by clicking on the magnifying glass you will find the actual string does not contain these escape chars. :) I hope that clarifies this for you. Both the regex and serializing produce the same json.

Comment: i saw this on  postman  so this is what a user will see if he send a request to my api

Comment: Sorry even in postman I cannot re-create this issue. [ScreenShot](https://i.gyazo.com/b97a9db13d0aa59f83f5bf0c645c9fde.png)

Comment: no problem i know what is the problem now, and thank you for your answer , thank you for your support

Comment: Hey @abderrahmaneMustapha could you possibly share what your problem and solution was please? I'm having this same issue now, too.

Comment: helloo @BronThulke we completely switched to .net core